# Is it possible to use an alternate CDN for AMP as ampproject.org is blocked in China?

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to use an alternate CDN for including the main JavaScript file AMP needs? Can a different URL than `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js` be used? Are there plans to open this up a bit more by allowing other CDNs that aren't blocked in China, etc?

Using several of the top proxies returned from a web search, it appears that `ampproject.org` is blocked in China. This isn't too surprising as other Google properties are blocked.

Edit: I should mention I tried copying the file and running it locally, but the AMP validator throws an error when I try that.

Comment: China has their own AMP clone called [MIP](https://www.mipengine.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the source file of the main Javascript the AMP need is only accessible using the `https://cdn.ampproject.org` URL.

According to the blog "[Getting started with AMP Html, accelerated mobile pages](http://ampready.com/getting-started)"

> AMP does this by creating new rules for bottlenecks: JavaScript and html elements that are considered slow are prohibited. **JavaScript is only allowed using libraries provided by the CDN of Google itself**.

Also in their official web page:

> Our goal with AMP HTML is reliable performance, so we designed it to be easily cacheable by content delivery networks (CDNs). **Google is offering a service that delivers AMP HTML documents given their URL through its CDN**. Others can use this service or make their own or serve AMP HTML pages from a plain-old-web-server.

Answer (score 4):

The JS should no longer be blocked in China.

Answer (score 3):

Cloudflare now provides an alternative to Google's AMP cache: https://blog.cloudflare.com/accelerated-mobile/

Answer (score 3):

Matt Mower posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mdmower/b56e94f0dc36beafb825b0c5e31fceef) explaining how to self-host AMP framework. That worked for me.

**summary of his post:**

1. Build AMP framework / download dist files (listed [here](https://cdn.ampproject.org/files.txt))
2. Serve them from the same http server as AMP HTML file.
3. Replace scripts `src` attributes. I.E: `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>` → `<script async src="<path_to_amp_files>/v0.js"></script>`
4. Customize `runtime-host` meta tag. Prepend `<meta name="runtime-host" content="<path_to_amp_files>">` before any script tags in head element.
5. There is a little more workaround for `amp-geo-api` in the gist.