# Is it ok to self-host the AMP Project javascript?

Tags: amp-html

I want to host the javascript myself to make sure I know the code being distributed to my users. Is it possible? Would there be consequences?

(I'm assuming the javascript can be built from https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use an alternate CDN for AMP as ampproject.org is blocked in China?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312339/is-it-possible-to-use-an-alternate-cdn-for-amp-as-ampproject-org-is-blocked-in-c)

Comment: yes, particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/61203785/207119

Answer (score 0):

Basically, AMP is a way to build web pages for static content that render fast. AMP in action consists of three different parts:

> **AMP HTML** is HTML with some restrictions for reliable performance and some extensions for building rich content beyond basic HTML. The **AMP JS** library ensures the fast rendering of AMP HTML pages. The **Google AMP Cache** can be used to serve cached AMP HTML pages.

AFAIK, AMP Project JavaScript is only accessible using the `https://cdn.ampproject.org` URL.

> JavaScript is powerful, it can modify just about every aspect of the page, but it can also block DOM construction and delay page rendering (see also Adding interactivity with JavaScript). To keep JavaScript from delaying page rendering, AMP allows only asynchronous JavaScript.
>
> AMP pages can’t include any author-written JavaScript. Instead of using JavaScript, interactive page features are handled in custom AMP elements. The custom AMP elements may have JavaScript under the hood, but they’re carefully designed to make sure they don’t cause performance degradation.

Also in my older post regarding [Is there a way to use an alternate CDN for including the main JavaScript file AMP needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39329944/5995040).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not trivial, but there is [a very detailed guide from Matt Mower](https://gist.github.com/mdmower/b56e94f0dc36beafb825b0c5e31fceef).

Essentially, all you have to do is change some configurations before building, fix your html `<meta>` and `<src>` tags to point to your hosted version, set an extra `<meta>` tag for dynamically loaded components and, depending on the amp plugins you use, configure your server to replace some strings in the plugins javascript.